# Support for OR constraint when querying questions based on tags

Tags: feature-request, api-v2, api, documentation

Right now, there is no way (as far as I know) to query for questions based on multiple tags using an `OR` constraint.

You can query for questions tagged with multiple of these tags, but not with one or many of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tagged` parameter to [`/search`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search) and related methods is an `OR`.

[This query](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/search?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=c#;java&site=stackoverflow) will return questions tagged `c#` or `java`, for example.

Or is rather expensive, which is one (of the many) reasons those methods are limited in how many results they return.

Comment: Hmm never actually thought about how expensive a query like that could be, but it would still be nice to have.

Comment: @tolgap it is available on `/search`, which returns questions; `/search` is just more limited than `/questions` in how many results it can return.